# Scala (Slick) HList splitting to case classes

Tags: scala, slick

currently I have a HList with more than 22 fields and now I want to split it to

2-3 case classes, is there an easy functional way to do it?
Currently I use the following syntax:

```
CaseClass1(c.head, c.tail.head, c.tail.tail.head, etc...)
```

However that doesn't seem to be right since I have a really big tail part now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tuple functionality in shapeless you could do:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)

val hlist =  1 :: "a" :: 2 :: "b" :: HNil
Foo.tupled(hlist.take(2).tupled)
```

Comment: I'm on shapeless 2.2 and actually I get: `could not find implicit value for parameter take: shapeless.ops.tuple.Take`

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt So if you try `(1 :: "a" :: HNil).take(1)` in the console, you don't get `1 :: HNil` ?

Comment: It's a slick hlist: `import slick.collection.heterogeneous._` can't change it, it's autogenerated by slick

Comment: Turning a Slick HList into a shapeless HList, does not seem to be that simple. There is some info and unworking code on [this Slick issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/519).